# Adding relevant links to other forums onto questions?

Tags: discussion

My primary interest is in the philosophy of science, with an emphasis on science. I thought it would potentially be a good idea to link relevant philosophy.SE posts to questions on your board. I was going to do this by appending these links, sparingly, to the bottom of physics.SE questions.

My first attempt was rejected. Here are the questions I tried to link: [Is Newton's Law of Gravity consistent with General Relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/89/is-newtons-law-of-gravity-consistent-with-general-relativity) on physics.SE and [Have there really been paradigm shifts?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/2602/have-there-really-been-paradigm-shifts) on philosophy.SE ([suggested edit](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/6133)). The latter addresses the case of one theory being rejected for another--are the theories necessarily incompatible, and if they are not, what is their relationship to one another? Newtonian mechanics and GTR are referenced.

I understand that sharing a link is not a standard edit, but thought that the benefit to members of both communities would outweigh this (of course, lacking the requisite reputation points, I was not able to place it in the comments section like a normal person). Cross-pollination of ideas between forums is always interesting, and I think providing relevant "exolinks" would facilitate it. Would the physics.SE community reconsider allowing me to make such edits?

Comment: I agree with Manishearth and disagree with linking metaphysics to physics questions here.

Answer (score 2):

First, a note:

Generally in-site cross linking can be done by putting a hatnote (using `>`), which makes the post look like:

> > Related: link link link
>
> Blah blah post

---

Now, I guess the main issue here was the fact that you tried linking Physics and Philosophy. Sure, they're related and relevant -- but generally we don't go into metaphysics while dealing with physics. I really see no viable link between the two questions myself -- the philosophy one may mention the two theories, but the answer there isn't really helpful if one wants to understand the *physics* of it.

Also, such "related:" headers are better posted in comments unless the relationship is clear-cut (and it's on the same site). It's not too hard to get 50 rep :)

Comment: @QuietThud: Yeah, but it's better if it's kept in an inobtrusive place like comments.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Sorry if I was out of line with my proposal. I felt that a link between the questions would help interested but wary physics.SE browsers find their way to relevant questions on the philosophy board, and vice versa. It certainly is not necessary to do metaphysics while one is doing physics, but as the many soft questions on your board support, it is still useful to keep it in the backdrop.

Comment: One of the worst experiences for me has been moving from hard science to philosophy, because I wanted to do a more self-directed analysis of science than my program allowed--only to discover that science is not adequately appreciated by a lot of contemporary philosophy that should really benefit from it. This has always confused me and I am continually looking for ways to fix it. 

Philosophy.SE is a new board, still in its beta stage, and I thought attracting more scientists to it from the start would be beneficial to both communities. I hope that some of you find yourself posting there!

Comment: You are, of course, right about links belonging in comments. Thank you for taking the time to listen to me. Have a nice day! And always remember your towel.

Answer (score 2):

Links of this nature are appropriate in comments, but inappropriate to be edited into the post itself. (Except that the original poster can always add any links or make any other edits they like.) So you will just have to wait until you get enough reputation to comment on any post - 50 rep I believe.

Note that this is different from adding a link that clarifies (rather than adds to) the question. For example, converting a technical term used in the question into a link to the Wikipedia page for that term is generally okay.